# Check if mouse\keyboard is active using Batch or PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, keyboard, mouse

I have been searching for this for a long time, and can't find one single answer.

Is it possible to check if my mouse or keyboard is in use (the mouse is currently moving or keys are being pressed) using only a `Batch` or `PowerShell` script? If yes, how?

Comment: You're trying to determine if the mouse is currently moving or keys are being pressed?

Comment: Exactly! I will add this to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the mouse movement, you could check the position of the pointer and calculate if there is a change over time.

```
$p1 = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5  # or use a shorter intervall with the -milliseconds parameter
$p2 = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
if($p1.X -eq $p2.X -and $p1.Y -eq $p2.Y) {
    "The mouse did not move"
} else {
    "The mouse moved"
}
```

As for the keys, you might want to try a similar technique utilizing the [`get-keystroke` script](http://obscuresecurity.blogspot.de/2013/06/Get-Keystroke.html) (which is basically a keylogger).